# Sublime Text Key Bindings

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm looking for a solution to bind *ctrl+j*, *ctrl+i*, *ctrl+l* and *ctrl+k* to *left*, *up*, *right*, *down* respectively, but without success.

This is what I've been trying (*Key Bindings - User*):

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+j"], "command": "left" },
    { "keys": ["Ctrl+l"], "command": "right" },
    { "keys": ["Ctrl+i"], "command": "up" },
    { "keys": ["Ctrl+k"], "command": "down" }
]
```

Sublime has been restarted, but with no difference.

Anyone has a solution? Please advice,
Thank you

Comment: Is this in html or what?

Comment: No this is JSON, please see documentation: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html

Comment: no, is the json being used in html to create interactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but the commands to move the cursor aren't what you think they are. The command you want to use is `move`, with arguments `by` and `forward` to specify which way to move and by how much.

If you open the Sublime console with `View > Show Console` or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+`</kbd>, you can enter the following command to get Sublime to tell you what command it's executing in response to your actions (run it again with `False` or restart Sublime to turn the logging off):

```python
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

If you then press the cursor keys for moving the cursor, you'll see the console telling you what commands are doing the move for you:

```
command: move {"by": "characters", "forward": false}
command: move {"by": "characters", "forward": true}
command: move {"by": "lines", "forward": false}
command: move {"by": "lines", "forward": true}
```

This tells you that the command `move` shifts the cursor around, and that you move by `characters` to move left and right and by `lines` to move up and down, with `forward` describing the direction.

With that knowledge, the key bindings that you want would look more like this:

```json
[
    { 
        "keys": ["ctrl+j"], "command": "move", 
        "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": false } 
    },
    { 
        "keys": ["ctrl+l"], "command": "move", 
        "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true } 
    },
    { 
        "keys": ["ctrl+i"], "command": "move", 
        "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": false} 
    },
    { 
        "keys": ["ctrl+k"], "command": "move", 
        "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true} 
    },
]
```

Comment: That was a relief! Thank you so much!